# Calculate the value which has the similar name in the header using - XLSWRITER using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter, pandas.excelwriter

I need to calculate the value which has the similar name in the header. Here i have **Bill** and **Non Bill** fields in the column. I need to calculate all the Bill separately and non-bill separately and need to **sum** in another column **Bill Amt Total** and **Non Bill Amt Total** using xlswrriter in python.

**Input file**

```
Name    | Bill - Php    | Non Bill - Php    | Bill - JS  | Non Bill -JS
Alex    |   30          |                   |      10    |
Ram     |   10          |          20       |            |
Stephen |               |                   |      20    |
Robert  |               |          10       |            |      10
Mohan   |               |          20       |      10    |
```

Output file:

```
Name    | Bill - Php    | Non Bill - Php    | Bill - JS  | Non Bill -JS | Bill Total Amt | Non Bill Total Amt
Alex    |   30          |                   |      10    |              |    40          |       
Ram     |   10          |          20       |            |              |    10          |   20
Stephen |               |                   |      20    |              |                |   20
Robert  |               |          10       |            |      10      |                |   20
Mohan   |               |          20       |      10    |              |     10         |   20
```

[image: Input file]

[image: Output file]

Comment: [Please do not paste data or sample code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Sure. I will send as data  here after

Comment: Thanks for updating. A minor issue: please do not mix up tabs and spaces in the pasted dataset next time, as this will hinder data import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select columns by string prefix (`str.startswith()`) and then perform horizontal sum by `df[selected_columns].sum(axis=1)`.

In addition, `Pandas` comes with Excel save/load capability, so you don't really need to import `xlsxwriter` or `openpyxl`.

### Data

The data is reproduced in Excel format.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Name    | Bill - Php  | Non Bill - Php  | Bill - JS  | Non Bill -JS
Alex    |   30        |                 |      10    |
Ram     |   10        |          20     |            |
Stephen |             |                 |      20    |
Robert  |             |          10     |            |      10
Mohan   |             |          20     |      10    |
"""), sep=r"\|\s*", engine='python')

# cleanup
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]
df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.strip()

# save .xlsx
df.to_excel("/mnt/ramdisk/data.xlsx", index=False)
```

## Solution

```
# load .xlsx
df = pd.read_excel("/mnt/ramdisk/data.xlsx")

for prefix in ("Bill", "Non Bill"):
    # select the columns to be summed
    cols_to_sum = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith(prefix)]
    # new column name
    col = f"{prefix} Amt Total"
    # sum the selected columns horizontally
    df[col] = df[cols_to_sum].sum(axis=1)
    # (optional) replace 0 with nan
    df[col] = df[col].replace({0.0: np.nan})

# save a new file
df.to_excel("/mnt/ramdisk/out.xlsx", index=False)
```

Check out the columns added:

```
print(df.iloc[:,-2:])
# Out[219]: 
#    Bill Amt Total  Non Bill Amt Total
# 0            40.0                 NaN
# 1            10.0                20.0
# 2            20.0                 NaN
# 3             NaN                20.0
# 4            10.0                20.0
```